# I'm reading this in a senior year physics text book, need to know if this is true, and if so then how? :

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics

"Even if a magnet is broken into atoms, each atom shall be a complete magnet. If the atom is further broken into electrons, protons, neutrons, etc. even then each particle shall behave like a complete magnet."

Comment: The point is that our particles have "spin", and this property provides magnetization.

Comment: so how does an electron, which always has spin +/- .5,from a magnetic material differ from electrons from any other material? as i know it, the atom behaves like a magnet when the spin of the electrons get aligned. Moreover, how do protons and neutrons behave as dipoles... this is quite confusing.

Comment: Non-rigorously: in other materials the signal is too weak, there is no coherence between all of the spins.

Comment: I suspect the text has defined a 'complete magnet' as having both a north and a south pole, and that no matter how the magnet is broken down, there will never be just north or just south poles.

Answer (score 1):

You will learn at some point that magnetism in materials, i.e. **magnetization**, comes from the material having a coherent collection of "spins". Each particle has **spin**, some quantum-mechanical feature, and as a result you get "spin magnetic moments" (which has a direction), which induces the magnetization.

So breaking down the material doesn't affect the existence of "spins", which is what you ultimately need for magnetization.